# Excel Date data validation

Tags: excel, date, validation

for excel cell, i want to do a validation of date. the format of the cell is date (dd/MM/yyyy) .
however validation is

`=AND(ISNUMBER(F6),LEFT(CELL("format",F6),1)="D")`

which validates that it should not contains alphabets and format is MM/dd/yyyy. How do i switch it to validate dd/MM/yyyy instead?

Comment: Cell function has limited number of formats and it is therefore tricky to trap such cases. You can try through a VBA UDF.

Comment: Yes in theory the format for DD/MM/YY would be D4 but I'm not sure it would work in practice because Cell with Format doesn't produce an immediate update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf